# Mock a function call in scala for unittesting

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalamock

I would like to write a unittest to the function

```scala
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.{DateTime, richReadableInstant}

def myFunction(ts: Long):Long = {
  (new DateTime(ts) to DateTime.now()).toDurationMillis
}
```

Is it possible to somehow mock Datetime.now(), so that the test result does not depend on when the test is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see this library is a wrapper around `joda-time` (which, as the official documentation recommends, should be dropped in favor of `java.time`, but I assume you have some constraint that forces you to work on a pre-Java 8 release).

`joda-time` comes with a collection of static helpers that, among other things, allow you to manage what the response is when a method asks for the "current time" (see their JavaDoc [here](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html)).

The easiest possible way (but possibly prone to mistakes due to the shared mutable state it relies on) would look like the following:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.{DateTime, richReadableInstant}
import org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils

DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(42)

def myFunction(ts: Long):Long = {
  (new DateTime(ts) to DateTime.now()).toDurationMillis
}

assert(myFunction(42) == 0)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/g5EYgW5jSFGk1sCJ9Fo87g/3).

As mentioned, this approach is a bit clunky and relies on shared mutable state, which makes it prone to confusing errors. You can build a nice small helper to make sure you can use a custom clock on a specific test and reset to the system clock once done. The required synchronization means a performance hit, but it's probably acceptable for your tests.

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.{DateTime, richReadableInstant}
import org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils
import org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider

def myFunction(ts: Long):Long = {
  (new DateTime(ts) to DateTime.now()).toDurationMillis
}

final class FixedClock(at: Long) extends MillisProvider {
  override def getMillis(): Long = at
}

def withCustomClock[A](clock: MillisProvider)(f: => A): A = {
  synchronized {
    try {
      DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisProvider(clock)
      f
    } finally {
      DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem() // _always_ reset to the system clock once done
    }
  }
}

assert(myFunction(42) > 1000000)

withCustomClock(new FixedClock(at = 42)) {
  assert(myFunction(42) == 0)
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  assert(myFunction(42) == 0)
}

assert(myFunction(42) > 1000000)
```

You can play around with this other example here on [this other worksheet on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/g5EYgW5jSFGk1sCJ9Fo87g/12).